# Java code works when referenced from a variable but throws an error when called directly

Tags: java, assertj

I created an assertion using AssertJ library. I stored the extraction from a node contained in an API response in a string variable. I referenced the variable in the assertion. It works, but when the code is passed directly in the assertion, it throws a Predicate error.

```
//Style 1
JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();
String s = jsonPath.get("name"); //stored in a variable
Assertions.assertThat(s).contains("test"); // no error when referenced here

//Style 2
 JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();
 Assertions.assertThat(jsonPath.get("name")).contains("test"); //throws an error when used directly


//error
Ambiguous method call. Both
assertThat
(Predicate<Object>)
in Assertions and
assertThat
(IntPredicate)
in Assertions match
```

Comment: If you are regularly doing JSON assertions, I would reocmmend https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit which has support for JsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions.assertThat((String)jsonPath.get("name"))
Cast to string it will work

Answer (score 1):

It is something called Ambiguous method, basically due to the fact that T could implement an interface I and there is an `assertThat(I)` in Assertions making the compiler confused whether to use `assertThat(String)` or `assertThat(I)`.
So in your case, cast to string for the method: `(String) jsonPath.get("name")` should work